# cordova -v produce un error... alguna solución?

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework, ng-cordova

[image: Este es el error que arroja cuando aplico el comando cordova -v]

El comando "cordova -v" o "cordova --version", me produce un error, todo estaba funcionando muy bien y de un momento a otro cordova dejó de funcionar.

Comment: Revisa las asociaciones de los archivos `.js` para que se abran siempre con `node.exe`

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario, como se hace esto? en ionic1 esto era automático, ahora necesito trabajar con un proyecto antiguo de ionic1 y me envia errores en cordova, como unifico todas las librerias para que puedan trabajar sin problemas.

Comment: No soy un experto, pero parece ser un problema de asociaciones de archivos de windows. Para probar lo que te dije, con el navegador de windows busca algun archivo `.js`, boton derecho del ratón, `Abrir con`, selecciona `node.exe` y asegurate de marcar "abrir siempre"

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, luego de mucho buscar encontré la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Esto me funcionó a mí.

La respuesta está en el sistema windows, en las variables de entorno de windows allí hay que ir al path (RUTA) y eliminar la ruta que direccionaba erróneamente a cordova.

Ruta mala eliminar:
C:\Users(nombre de usuario)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova;

Al eliminar esta ruta del PATH, y luego guardar cambios y reiniciar, todo se arregló.
Previamente desinstalé Cordova: npm uninstall cordova -g y luego npm install -g cordova@6.1.1  que es la versión que estoy trabajando con ionic v1.

Saludos